# How to set the value of UILabel in iphone?

Tags: uilabel

I'm doing this to set the value in UILabel:

```
NSMutableDictionary *responseDict = [responseString objectFromJSONString];

self.pkrLbl.text= [responseDict objectForKey:@"amount"];
```

and I'm getting this error:

```
[__NSCFNumber isEqualToString:]: unrecognized selector sent to instance 0x9440310
```

2013-05-16 15:23:34.281 EasyLoadPakistan[20341:19a03] *** Terminating app due to uncaught exception 'NSInvalidArgumentException', reason: '-[__NSCFNumber isEqualToString:]: unrecognized selector sent to instance 0x9440310'

Please help me how can I set value in UIlabel

Answer (score 0):

A UILabel expects a string (specifically `NSString` or one of its subclasses), and you are passing it a number (an `NSNumber` instance).

Convert the number to a string first, then set the label to that string:

```
NSNumber *n =  [responseDict objectForKey:@"amount"];
NSString *stringVersion = [n stringValue];

self.pkrLbl.text = stringVersion;
```

If you prefer to have it all on one line, you can omit the variables and just chain the `stringValue` call. The approach shown above tends to facilitate debugging, though (you can for instance set a breakpoint and have a look at your variables).